# Unable to import pandas in QGIS Windows

Tags: qgis, installation, qgis-processing, windows, pandas

I am trying to import pandas 0.20.3 in QGIS console but it's giving me this error.
Could any one help me to solve this problem.
I used pip to install pandas in windows and QGIS version is 2.14

[image]

Comment: Welcome to gis.stackexchange! Please note that a good question on this site is expected to show some degree of research on your part, i.e. what you have tried and - if applicable - code so far. For more info, you can check our [faq].

Answer (score 0):

There is an [issue](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/16715) when installing pandas with pip. Try uninstalling pandas and numpy from pip and reinstall numpy and then reinstall pandas

Comment: But I am able to access pandas in python interpreter of windows.
Could you suggest how I should install pandas?